# AS3 can't load XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm making a quiz app on flash builder with AS3.

I want to load a XML file to get my questions. But I think I can't load my XML file. I googled alot. I searched the forums. But nothing worked. I just don't see my error here.

When I click the button I want to see on my stage if my XML file is loaded. But in this case I don't get any value on my stage.

Quiz.as

```
package
{   
    [SWF('width'= 800, 'height' = 600, 'frameRate'=40)]
    public class Quiz extends Sprite
    {
                // gloabal container 
        public static var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
        // button object 
        public var btnMulti:MyButton = new MyButton();

        public function Quiz()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void {
            addChild(container);
            makeMenu();
        }


        private function makeMenu():void {
            btnMulti.buttonText = "multipleChoice";
            btnMulti.x = 50;
            btnMulti.y = 20;
            btnMulti.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, multiHandler);
                        // add button to the stage
            container.addChild(btnMulti);
        }

        private function multiHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            // if button clicked make a Question object
            var q:Question = new Question();

            // get the value
            var questionText:String = q.getter;

            // print the value in a textfield on the stage
            var tField:TextField = new TextField();
            tField.text = questionText;
            container.addChild(tField);
        }

    }
}
```

Question.as

```
public class Question extends Sprite
    {
        private var test:String;    

        public function Question()
        {
            // xml
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./files/multiplechoice.xml"); 
            var urlLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);
            urlLoad.load(urlReq); 
        }

        private function textLoaded(e:Event):void {
            XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
            var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

            // check if loaded
            test = "xml loaded";
        }

        // getter
        public function get getter():String {
            return test.questionText;
        }
    }
```

multiplechoice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multipleChoice>
    <questionSet>
        <question>Question 1</question>
        <answer correct="yes">Answer 1</answer>
        <answer>Answer 2</answer>
        <answer>Answer 3</answer>
        <answer>Answer 4</answer>
    </questionSet>

    <questionSet>
        <question>Question 2</question>
        <answer correct="yes">Answer 1</answer>
        <answer>Answer 2</answer>
        <answer>Answer 3</answer>
        <answer>Answer 4</answer>
    </questionSet>

    <questionSet>
        <question>Question 3</question>
        <answer correct="yes">Answer 1</answer>
        <answer>Answer 2</answer>
        <answer>Answer 3</answer>
        <answer>Answer 4</answer>
    </questionSet>
</multipleChoice>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have a callback for the textLoaded, but you aren't waiting for it to load, before you call the getter().  Try this first:

```
public function get getter():String {
    if(test) {
        return test.questionText;
    } else {
        return "Data not available";
    }
```

but you can also pass a function reference to the Question class to pass the value back when it's loaded.  You might want to think about preloading the questions in any event.

```
public class Question extends Sprite
{
    private var test:String;
    private var callback:Function; 

    public function Question(_callback:Function)
    {
        this.callback = _callback;
        // xml
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./files/multiplechoice.xml"); 
        var urlLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);
        urlLoad.load(urlReq); 
    }

    private function textLoaded(e:Event):void {
        urlLoad.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);

        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

        // check if loaded
        this.callback(xml);
    }
}


// in the main class
    private function multiHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        // if button clicked make a Question object
        var q:Question = new Question(this.questionCallback);

    }

    public function questionCallback(xml:XML):void
        // get the value from the xml

        var tField:TextField = new TextField();
        tField.text = <<parsed xml....>>;
        container.addChild(tField);
    }
```

You might want to make the textfield and question class properties and not keep the scope local to the functions so you access to them as well.